# Conditional formatting if cell in another sheet is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting

I have a Google Sheets [Calendar](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1loRAS8It7iTU8C00UDsFe1dCIweT7hl_qKE5Y6bKUZ8/edit?usp=sharing) which I use to track bookings. The 1st sheet is the whole year summary with the following being detailed months.
I would like the 'Year' sheet to indicate if a particular date is available or not.

If I have written in January 1st (January!B5) "*Booked for X*" - for example, I want the corresponding date on the 'Year' sheet (in this case (Year!B4)) text to turn red.

I have tried some conditional formatting along the lines of `=NOT(ISBLANK(January!B5))` with no success.

Is there another formula or Script I could write to do this, what feels like, very simple task.

EDIT: I have just realised that you can't use conditional formatting between 2 sheets - correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can use conditional formatting between sheets but you have to use indirect e.g. =NOT(ISBLANK(indirect("January!B5")))  (not tested).

Comment: Ah so simple, thank you @TomSharpe